# How to remove a dynamically created button in gridview

Tags: c#, .net, gridview

I'm trying to find a way to remove an item that has been dynamically added when I change my drop down list selected user. The way this works is I add an edit and delete button dynamically when I select a user. I need to have the existing one be removed when I change users. Here is the code I'm using to build the two buttons. How do I remove them? Do I wipe out the columns and then add the columns again?

```
try
{
    dgvBG.DataSource = this.bgDataTableAdapter.GetData(cbPatientID.SelectedItem.ToString());
    try
    {
        Image editBGImg = Properties.Resources.editor;
        Image delBGImg = Properties.Resources.del;
        DataGridViewImageColumn btnBGEdit = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
        DataGridViewImageColumn btnBGDel = new DataGridViewImageColumn();                            
        btnBGEdit.HeaderText = "Edit";
        btnBGDel.HeaderText = "Delete";
        btnBGEdit.Image = editBGImg;
        btnBGDel.Image = delBGImg;
        btnBGEdit.Width = 35;
        btnBGDel.Width = 42;
        dgvBG.Columns.Add(btnBGEdit);
        dgvBG.Columns.Add(btnBGDel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code. It may be better to hide them than remove them.

```
for (int i = dgvBG.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var col = dgvBG.Columns[i];

    if (col.HeaderText == "Edit" || col.HeaderText == "Delete" )
    {
        dgvBG.Columns.Remove(col);
        // col.Visible = false;
    }
}
```